# Spark scala flatmapvalues

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After performing few transformations in Spark-shell, I got the output as below. I am copy and pasting from REPL.

scala> s.collect
res44: Array[(String, String)] = Array((45000,Pavan,Amit), (50000,Bhupesh,Tejas,Dinesh)

Now i need to generate individual files for each ID, with ID included in File Name as below

```
The file with name ID45000.txt should have below content
45000,Pavan
45000,Amit

The file with name ID50000.txt should have below content.
50000,Bhupesh
50000,Tejas
50000,Dinesh
```

Tried below code but not working

```
s.foreach{case(k,v) => flatMapValues(x=>x.split(",")).saveAsTextFile("ID"+k+".txt")}
```

Could experts kindly help me.

Comment: Many Thanks, Ramesh, I am new to stackoverflow and could not view your response early. I am executing the code in REPL. After applying few transformations I got the output in REPL., which I copy and pasted as Array[(String, String)] = Array((45000,Pavan,Amit).
 (50000,Bhupesh,Tejas,Dinesh)). My next step is to generate individual file for each ID with columns ID and name, and file name should have ID included. 45000,Pavan
45000,Amit in file ID45000.txt and 50000,Bhupesh
50000,Tejas
50000,Dinesh in file ID50000.txt. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies Ramesh, if I am not clear.As per my understanding, In the Array[(String, String)], The id is considered as one string and all the names as another string

Comment: Sandeep I have answered below :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `s` *rdd* is

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((45000,Pavan,Amit), (50000,Bhupesh,Tejas,Dinesh)
```

doing the following should work ( not an efficient solution though).

```
val groupedRDD = s.flatMap{case(k, v)=> v.split(",").map(x => (k, x))}.groupByKey()

val keySetToCheck = groupedRDD.collect().toMap.keySet
for(key <- keySetToCheck){
  groupedRDD.filter(x => x._1 == key).saveAsTextFile("ID"+key+".txt")
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Many Thanks, Ramesh for your kind solution. Is this possible, with out using collect().

Comment: Nope I gess not . but you can collect the keys only though instead of collecting all data.